# Gparted: the boot texts appear but GUI does not

Tags: gparted, liveusb

I had an issue with booting Windows10 cause somehow I lost all my partitions on the SSD where my windows was installed. I am trying to recover that using Gparted live USB. The boot process starts with selection of OS flavour, then I get prompts for selecting language and other standard questions to select key map etc. After that, the screen goes blank where the GUI is supposed to appear. The monitor turns off saying no signal or DP or HDMI (tried both). Any suggestions please? let me know if this is not the right forum for this question.